# assert_match the path of image_url with the json_response

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have written a test to assert_match the path of image_url with the json_response.

In cards_controller_test.rb,

```
def test_index
  get :index, { client: "e59db1f42d665da2c8bae1196d7f042d91ef4b33295554024d7eb59ab9f298fc", sig: "e0ZHbZqCB8Tf4kWWxShEFyoJf5c" }
  assert_response :success
  assert_match "/system/cards/marketing_images/816/119/124/original/d712c1fe45ab90f2cb058dec0ea4370e1968d54d.png", json_response["marketing_image_url"] 
end
```

Currently, the test is green. But I must use model.attachment.url to generate the url & then match it with response. Not sure how this can be done.

Comment: what is the issue in using `model.attachment.url`?

Comment: @shivam Expected /\/marketing_images\/original\/missing\.png/ to match "/system/cards/marketing_images/816/119/124/original/d712c1fe45ab90f2cb058dec0ea4370e1968d54d.png".